# Join multiple document types exists in single MongoDB Collection / Container

Tags: mongodb

Please consider following data model where it is designed to put multiple types of documents into single sharded MongoDB collection or container.
post_comment_reaction_combined_collection

```
{
    "id": "<post-id>",
    "type": "post",
    "postId": "<post-id>",
    "userId": "<post-author-id>",
    "title": "<post-title>",
    "content": "<post-content>",
    "creationDate": "<post-creation-date>"
}

{
    "id": "<comment-id>",
    "type": "comment",
    "postId": "<post-id>",
    "userId": "<comment-author-id>",
    "content": "<comment-content>",
    "creationDate": "<comment-creation-date>"
}

{
    "id": "<like-id>",
    "type": "like",
    "postId": "<post-id>",
    "userId": "<liker-id>",
    "creationDate": "<like-creation-date>"
}
```

We have requirement to combine / join these documents types to provide following output.

Example Input -

```
{ 
"id": "post-id", 
"type": "post", 
"postId": "post-id", 
"userId": "post-author-id-1", 
"title": "post-title", 
"content": "post-content"
} 

{ 
"id": "comment-id-1", 
"type": "comment", 
"postId": "post-id",
 "userId": "comment-author-id-1", 
"content": "comment-content-1"
} 

{ 
"id": "comment-id-2", 
"type": "comment", 
"postId": "post-id", 
"userId": "comment-author-id-2", 
"content": "comment-content-2"
} 

{ 
"id": "comment-id-3",
 "type": "comment", 
"postId": "post-id", 
"userId": "comment-author-id-3", 
"content": "comment-content-"
}
```

Example Output -

```
{ 
"id": "post-id", 
"type": "post", 
"postId": "post-id", 
"userId": "post-author-id-1", 
"title": "post-title", 
"content": "post-content"
"comments": [
{
"id": "comment-id-1", ….
} ,
{
"id": "comment-id-2", ….
},
{
"id": "comment-id-3", ….
}
],
"totalCommentCount": 3
}
```

Is it possible to do above transformation efficiently in single query or aggregation pipeline in MongoDB? I would also like to compare single container having different types and having separate container for each type data modeling, What are the pros and cons, will there be scalability concerns in Sharding?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/P1agbem4xgY

aggregate code:

```
    db.post.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "comments",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "postId",
      "as": "comments"
    }
  }
])
```

here we are doing lookup with comments based on postid

As you have all documents in same collection then you can consider using below(self lookup!) https://mongoplayground.net/p/wVGUL2b18fn

```
    db.post_comments.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "post_comments",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "postId",
      "as": "comments"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: As I mentioned  it is designed to put multiple types of documents into single sharded MongoDB collection or container. That means Post, Comment, Reaction Documents types are put into same collection, it s not designed to separately create collections for Post, Comment etc. - Post Collection, Comment Collection. We cannot use $lookup is here since Comment Documents are also sharded.

Comment: Edited my answer with self lookup!